# Codeigniter has a error with foreach loop

Tags: php, codeigniter

my problem is that, when i try to get a product detail from the table, i click on the product's name and it will lead me to product_detail, but when i run i show the problem is:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Can you have a look and tell me what can i do to solve this problem?
this is my view:

```
<?php foreach ($prod_detail as $ud) { }?>
<form method="POST" name="fr_update">
<input type="hidden" name="id_sp" value="<?php echo $ud->id_sp; ?>">
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
<div class="col-md-2">
    <p>Tên sản phẩm</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" style="max-width: 365px;" name="ten_sp" readonly value="<?php echo $ud->ten_sp;?>">

</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <p>Ngày sản xuất:</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4" style="padding-left: 0px">
    <input align="left" type="date" class="form-control" style="max-width: 365px;" name="ngay_sx" readonly value="<?php echo $ud->ngay_sx;?>"/>  
</div>
```

And this is my controller

```
function prod_detail($id_sp){
    $data['main_content'] = 'backend/home/manproduct/prod_detail_view';
    $this->load->model('product_model');
    $data['prod_detail'] = $this->product_model->getProdDetailByProdId($id_sp);
    $data['rows']= $this->membership_model->getUserData();
    $data['row']= $this->product_model->getProdData();
    $this->load->view('includes/admin/template', $data);
}
```

And this is my product_model

```
function getProdDetailByProdId($ten_sp){
    $this->db->where('ten_sp', $ten_sp);
    $query = $this->db->get('products');
    if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
        $data = $query->row();
        return $data->$id_sp;
    }
}
function getProdData(){
    $this->db->where('ten_sp', $ten_sp);
    $query = $this->db->get('products');
    if($query->num_rows()>0){
        foreach ($query->result() as $row){
            $data[]=$row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Comment: model methods don't return anything if `num_rows` conditions aren't met so you are passing undefined to `foreach` then

Comment: First line of first code block, there's a typo.
`<?php foreach ($prod_detail as $ud) { }?>` You are closing the `foreach`, you can't obviously get `$ud->id_sp` out of it's curly braces.

Comment: can you tell me how can i fix that, i am just a beginer

Comment: `<?php foreach ($prod_detail as $ud) { ?>` then at the end of your (foreached) html `<?php } ?>`

Comment: Take a look at, http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php. Where is `$prod_detail` defined?

Comment: @phaberest i did try it but it still that error

Comment: and the problem says that : Invalid argument supplied for foreach not about the value $ud

Comment: Try to `die(var_dump($data));` before `$this->load->view('includes/admin/template', $data);` in your controller to see what data you're passing to the view

Comment: woa, the error says that, undefine variable $id_sp on my controller, on my model :

Comment: `function getProdDetailByProdId($id_sp){
  $this->db->where('id_sp', $id_sp);
  $query = $this->db->get('products');
  if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
   $data = $query->row();
   return $data->$id_sp;`

Comment: Where u calling this function prod_detail($id_sp)

Comment: @devpro $data['prod_detail'] = $this->product_model->getProdDetailByProdId($id_sp);

Comment: U r calling it inside the controller function I am asking about this function function prod_detail($id_sp) are u getting Id_sp from URL?

Comment: yes, but it has error

Comment: or did u defined it in route: $route['prod_detail/(:any)'] = "controllerName/prod_detail/$1"; ??

Comment: or you make an if statement before foreach that foreach will only work if $prod_detail is not empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Are fetching only one row not an array..

```
 function getProdDetailByProdId($ten_sp){
        $this->db->where('ten_sp', $ten_sp);
        $query = $this->db->get('products');
        if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
            $data = $query->row(); //here
            return $data->$id_sp;
        }
    }

 $data['prod_detail'] = $this->product_model->getProdDetailByProdId($id_sp);
```

This Wont Give You an array Its only gives You row..

Answer (score 0):

```
$query->row();
```

This method returns a single result row. If your query has more than one row, it returns only the first row. The result is returned as an object.

So no need to use `foreach` if you still want to use foreach then use `$query->result()` instead of `$query->row()`